# Number of ways to reflect a beam in a grid.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, computational-geometry

Given a rectangular grid of $n*m$ and co-ordinates of two points $a$ and $b$ we need to find the number of directions we can send a beam from $a$ such that it passes through $b$ and doesn't travel more than distance than $k$ units? It follows normal laws of reflection and reflection occurs at the edges of the rectangle.

Comment: "passes `through` $b$" ?

Comment: Does reflection occur when x-axis is a mirror?

Comment: @Narasimham all the four walls of the grid are mirrors

Comment: Hint: tile the plane with reflected copies of the $n\times m$ box.

Comment: @amd what does tiling the plane mean?

Comment: Fill it with copies of the box. Then, instead of trying to work out all of the reflected paths you can simply draw straight lines.

Comment: What is the reflected ray if you hit a corner?

Comment: @amd it bounces back.